# Evaluate the Modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_0(z)$ for $z \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, bessel-functions

Consider the [Modified Bessel function of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) $K_0(z)$ for $z \to 0$.

Some sources (Abramowitz and Stegun, formula 9.6.8, and [this page](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.30), formula 10.30.3) state that

$$K_0(z) \sim - \log z$$

That is: $K_0(z)$ is *proportional* to $\log(z)$. But according to [Wolfram Alpa](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%7Bz+%5Cto+0%7D+BesselK%5B0%2Cz%5D) (in the "Series expansion at z = 0" section):

$$K_0(z) = \log \left( \frac{2}{\gamma z} \right) + O(z^2) = \log 2 - \log \gamma - \log z + O(z^2)$$

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html) constant. This is a more accurate result.

How can it be obtained? I can't find a source for this.

Comment: Well, no offense intended, but to speak of "accurate", you might want to resolve the confusion with $x$ and $z$.

Comment: The WA series expansion is for $K_1(x)/(xK_0(x))$ near $0$, isn't it? Also the first approximation is actually $K_0(x)\approx -\ln x$...

Comment: @ProfessorVector I just edited the post.

Comment: @d.k.o. Please, check out the link now: I edited and corrected it to the expansion of $K_0(z)$. I know that the approximation is right, but I would like to find a justification for the terms $\log 2 - \log \gamma$: they do not make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

$K_0$ can be expressed in terms of $I_0$ as follows:

$$
K_0(z)=AI_0(z)+BI_0(z)\int \frac{dx}{xI_0^2(x)},
$$
where $A=\ln 2-\gamma$ and $B=-1$ (*any solution of the underlying differential equation is of that form for arbitrary $A$ and $B$*). Since
$$
I_0(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{z^k}{(2k)!!}\right)^2,
$$
and $I_0(0)=1$,
\begin{align}
K_0(z)&=I_0(z)\left(\ln 2-\gamma-\ln z+\frac{z^2}{4}+\ldots\right) \\
&=\ln 2-\gamma-\ln z+O(z^2)
\end{align}
when $z\searrow 0$.